# Allow users to remove printers via group policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy, printing

We are deploying printers via group policy using Server 2008's Print Management role.

Some printers that were deployed by group policy earlier are no longer relevant, however they remain attached to workstations.

End users cannot right-click --> Remove these printers. They receive the following error:

```
Access is denied, unable to remove device
<printer-name> on <server-name>
```

Is there a group policy to allow domain users the ability to remove old network printers from their workstations? I have tried setting the following policy to "disabled" but without any success:

```
User Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Control Panel --> 
Printers --> Prevent deletion of printers
```

In addition to the above, some end users cannot open printing preferences as per the following error. I figure removing the printer and then reinstalling the printer with correct driver via group policy will resolve this issue.

[image: Printing Preferences protection fault error]

Answer (score 1):

I think [this thread holds the answer to your question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/bbbf2718-d9ce-4b8c-96fc-fa8484b14be7/).

> Yes, because the SYSTEM installed it, so this is the owner of the object, take a look inside the registry, the ACL on the printer connection inside HKCU should be set to owner=system.
>
> Change Printer deployment from "publish printer" (which is rubbish by design) and use GPP Printers. On the common tab (every common tab) of the user configuration you can check: Run in user logged in credentials
>
> If the use creates it, the user can delete it.
>
> Mark

Comment: I have looked in the Print Management console and Group Policy Management but have no idea how to use "GPP Printers". Also, where is the "common tab". Thanks!

Comment: @ash GPP is Group Policy Preferences. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc732092.aspx